# Adding a vaiable to a static file path

Tags: django, static

I have this line in some javascript

```
{ url: "{% static 'volumes/123.nxs' %}" }
```

the script does what it should, however I would like to replace the file name with a value from Django, `{{ context.number }}` I've tried simply doing the following but it does not work. Am I going in the right direction?

```
{ url: "{% static 'volumes/' + {{ context.number }} + '.nxs' %}" }
```

Side question, the file is currently in the static folder, but moving forward in might be better to have them in another folder not under Django (for various reasons), how would I go about setting some kind of multimedia folder?

Answer (score 1):

This does the job!

```
{% static '' %}volumes/{{ context.number }}.nxs
```